# Running spark.sql query in jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, jupyter

I am starting the jupyter notebook with

```
pyspark --driver-class-path /home/statspy/postgresql-42.2.23.jar --jars /home/statspy/postgresql-42.2.23.jar
```

I am running this in the jupyter:

```
import os
jardrv = '/home/statspy/postgresql-42.2.23.jar'
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', jardrv).getOrCreate()
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/dbname'
properties = {'user':'postgres', 'password':'secret'}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table='tbname', properties=properties)
```

then i can run:

```
df.printSchema()
```

and I get the schema.

But then I want to run queries like this:

```
spark.sql("""select * from tbname""")
```

and I get an error saying `table or view tbname not found`

What do I need to change to run a query with `spark.sql`  instead of use df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the dataframe as tempview before using `spark.sql`.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbname")
```